# Why don't review actions give reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, review

When going through the review queue recently, a thought occurred: if reviewing things like late answers or close votes helps the site, why don't they give reputation?  It would make sense to me that site users who take the time to go through the review queue and look over or improve posts that need help get rewarded with reputation.  If reputation is supposed to be a measure of how much the community trusts a user, and how helpful to the community that user is, wouldn't it make sense to award rep for taking actions that help the community?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They've been pretty firm about *only* providing reputation for *core* actions.

Those core actions are considered:

- Asking questions
- Answering questions

The only other thing you can get reputation for doing is getting confirmed suggested edits. That's it.

Reviewing stuff isn't a core action, it's a purely optional, privilege based activity.

Comment: Have they made blog posts or other documentation explaining *why* they've been so firm about this?

Comment: @DuckTapeAl not that I know of right off hand. Here is one of the SO moderators, a *lot* more of this kind of information is on meta.se: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163814/review-system-reputation

Comment: @DuckTapeAl The review queue gets done already without adding rep incentives, so there's no reason for them to award rep for it. They do give badges for it, but if further gamification isn't necessary for a task to get done to spec, further gamification won't be added.

Comment: @waxeagle link from SE staffer thing is dead/broken.

Answer (score 11):

A major problem for reviews is so-called "robo-reviewers", who click through queues for the review badges without *actually* reviewing - they just hit approve on everything, letting all the crap through that the review queues are supposed to keep out. The SE staff introduced review audits on certain large SE sites to try and stop people from doing this.

A totally reasonable concern is that giving people rep for reviews will make them more inclined to do that.

But mainly it's just: rep is obtained by being helpful where people can critically examine you, and that's in public in questions and answers.